# SCSS modify parent on action

Tags: sass, parent

i have a Checkbox in a List.

If it is checked - the Line should get an new Background-color.

Can i do this with SCSS?

```
<li><div><input type="checkbox"></input</div><div>test</div></li>
```

Like:

```
li{@if input:checked{background-color:#ff0000;}}
```

Comment: Your edit doesn't change anything.  This would have to be a function of CSS for this to work.

Comment: argh... could be so easy... Thanks for the help... :-(